# Nginx location block not working for links

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, next.js

I have the following:

```
location /ron-swanson-quotes/ {
  return 301 /ron-swanson/;
}
```

And a SSR React next.js app.

The rewrite here works for people visiting the site externally but not if I click on a internal link. Is nginx capable of listening to what happens in node or does nginx never know about them?

Edit: when it's linked externally it redirect fine. When it is clicked on from within the application Nginx logs as such:

```
[2018-03-05T19:06:13+00:00] #######.xyz 71.211.##.## "GET /communicator/paulo-coelho/ HTTP/1.1" 304 "http://####.xyz/x-paulo-coelho-quotes-that-will-soothe-your-aching-heart/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36" 1.180
```

Thanks!

Comment: Depends, what are you internal links? Do they match this path _exactly,_ or are they slightly different?

Comment: They match the path exactly. My gut feeling is that nginx doesn't even know about this the way I have it written because server.js takes care of the routing for the app. Internal links are basically React Router / Next Router <a href='/this'>This</a> which hits server.js req.path('/next')

Comment: How are you serving your `index.html` ? from Nginx or from an express route ?

Comment: Express. Nginx picks the request up but sends 304 so I think that's where express comes into play and routes it as it normally would, (normal isn't what I'd like. Nginx needs to handle it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

The package we are using is `custom-express-server`. I realized that instead of using nginx, the better option was to have an array of redirects and have a redirect in the custom express setup and a redirect for the front-end in `getInitialProps`.

When we did the redirect in getInitialProps, the page transitions broke so we had to hard code those in there.

Answer (score 2):

Is the development version of your front-end also SSR? You may need to just update the links from relative paths to absolute paths, and make sure to not use the React-Router Link component. React router could be dealing with the relative path, since it sees it as a front-end route, so use an absolute path instead without the link component to send the request through Nginx.

Example

Instead of this:

```
<Link to='/ron-swanson-quotes'>Ron Swanson</Link>
```

Do this:

```
<a href='https://yourronswansonwebsite.com/ron-swanson-quotes'>Ron Swanson</a>
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for you answer but upon further investigation in seems to be an nginx issue.